# Recursive query on SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a problem trying to do a recursive query with SQLAlchemy. I search and re-search over SO and every web I found, but I couldn't find what I need.

## What I want:

I have two tables with relations (the third one is not necessary in this case):

[image]

I want to get all the items contained by a container. The first container could have subcontainers or not (the field could be null) but in case the container has a subcontainer, I need to subquery again over table1 taking the subcontainerid as a containerid.

## What I have on Oracle:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.id,
                table1.containerid,
                table1.subcontainerid,
                table1.iditem
FROM table1
START WITH containerid IN (
    SELECT table2.id FROM table2 WHERE table2.id = X
)
CONNECT BY PRIOR table1.subcontainerid = containerid
```

## What I have tried on SQLAlchemy:

I get lot of DatabaseErrors like ‘cycle detected while executing recursive WITH query’, but the closest I’ve been, was in that try:

```
table1CTE = table1.query.with_entities(table1.id).\
    filter(table1.id == 19076).\
    cte(name='table1', recursive=True)

a = aliased(table1CTE, name="sb")
b = aliased(table2, name="bi")

joined = table2.query.with_entities(table2.containerid).\
    filter(a.c.id == b.subcontainerid)

cte = a.union(joined)

table2.query.with_entities(table2.id, table2.containerid, table2.iditem).\
    select_entity_from(cte).\
    all()
```

But this return all the fields in table1… So it isn’t what I need.

I know this question is a little hard to understand, so if you need something to make it easier, tell me.

Comment: Have you looked here? [Adjacency List Relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html)

Comment: First, thank you for your reply @Fian I read it, but I can not see how to do a recurisve query with that.

Comment: Could you please provide actual model/table definitions in Python instead of an image of your schema? Or if you're reflecting, then the SQL schema definition. It's not a major thing, since the tables are simple, but still.

Comment: `idcontainer` in `START WITH idcontainer IN` looks like a typo. Is it?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yes, it is a typo, thanks for tell it. I edited the question. About the models, I'm reflecting, and I cannot show the schema definition because I have a privacy contract about it, but I think the relationship it's as easier as you can see in the image.

Comment: Fair enough. I've never actually used Oracle, so I'm utterly unaware how CONNECT BY actually works, but to me it seems that your original query is recursive on *table1* only and uses *table2* just to get the initial rows. On the other hand the CTE seems to include *table2* in the iterative step as well.